# Как управлять доступностью команд в различных ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Привет.

Как в MVVM управляют доступностью команд из различных ViewModel?

Допустим, создается динамическое меню в одной ViewModel_1. Элементы этого меню привязаны к командам, и стоит задача управлять включением (отключением) кнопок ToolBar из другой ViewModel_2 при нажатии на пункты меню ViewModel_1.

Comment: Хм. А причём тут доступность команд к отображению кнопок?

Сделайте VM для кнопки (туда поместите и команду), заведите `ObservableCollection` этих VM (и упакуйте в VM для тулбара), привяжите к этой коллекции кнопки на тулбаре. Всё!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Я использую mvvmlight framework, в котором есть класс RelayCommand, который может принимать в конструкторе только функцию-делегат или, в дополнение к ней, ещё и условие доступности. Рекомендую посмотреть документацию по этому фреймворку, потому как данный подход используется и в других...

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону `Messaging`:

1. Из привязанной в `ViewModel_1` команде отправляете сообщение. Для
   `MVVM Light` это выглядело бы вот так:

   ```
   Messenger.Default.Send(new MenuItemClickedMessage());
   ```
2. В ViewModel_2 регистрируете обработчик сообщения:

   ```
   Messenger.Default.Register(this, OnMenuItemClickedMessage_Received);
   ```

   в котором присваиваете false переменным класса через которые управляете    доступностью Вашего Toolbar:

   ```
   public bool CanToolBarButtonClick()
   {
      return this.ToolBarButtonEnabled;
   }
   ```